# How many times has Squidward "won"?

Tags: spongebob-squarepants

The show *Spongebob Squarepants* usually isn't kind to Squidward, but there is one episode where Squidward creates a band (forgot the name of the episode) and actually *wins*. No negative repercussions for him, it was a pure triumph for him.

Are there any more episodes like this for Squidward, where everything goes well for him?

Comment: putting this comment from jj anderson's(https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/65538/jj-anderson ) answer  *You are refering to the band geeks episode. Christmas Who is another great ending for Squidward. *

Comment: I always remember this episode, loved it for this very reason.